# How to find all subordinates and their subordinates based on their multiple pernos

Tags: database, postgresql, common-table-expression

**Given:**

1. Two tables `Employee` `EmployeeManager`
2. Table Employee's columns: `perno`, `uniqueKey`. One employee can have mulitple different `perno`, but there's only one `uniqueKey` for an employee.
3. Table EmployeeManager's columns: `manger_perno`, `subordinate_perno`. `perno` column of the `Employee` table corresponds to `manager_perno` and `subordinate_perno` of `EmployeeManager`.
   There's no FK, just plain text values. Something like '123'.

```
// Example of tables' data.

EmployeeManager table:
manger_perno subordinate_perno 
3 4
5 6

Employee table:
uniqueKey perno
AAA 2
AAA 3
BBB 4
BBB 5
CCC 6
```

**Question:**
How to find subordinates and subordinates of subordinates for an employee with specified perno. For example if perno = 3 the result should be:
AAA 3 4
BBB 5 6

Ps. Also at some point of time manager and subordinate could be swaped:
3 4 ->
4 3

**The Algoritm I thought of:**

1. Find the `uniqueKey` for the given `perno`. [Will be AAA]
2. Find all the pernos where `uniqueKey` is `AAA` [2,3]
3. Find all the subordinates of these pernos [4]
4. (This is where the problem lays) Now I have to find `uniqueKey` of 4 and then find all the pernos that correspond to found `uniqueKey` [4,5]
5. Recursion.

My cte recursive solution doesn't work (no suprise, huh) - endless recursion:

```
WITH RECURSIVE cte AS (
  SELECT
    emp.uniqueKey AS unique_key,
    emp2.perno AS man_perno,
    man.subordinate_perno AS sub_perno
  FROM
    employee emp
  INNER JOIN
    employee emp2 ON emp.uniqueKey = emp2.uniqueKey  // Find uniqueKey by perno
  INNER JOIN
    employee_manager man ON man.manager_perno = emp2.perno  // Find actual subordinates pernos
  WHERE
    emp.perno = <perno>

  UNION ALL

  SELECT
    emp.uniqueKey AS unique_key,
    emp2.perno AS man_perno,
    man.subordinate_perno AS sub_perno
  FROM
    cte
  INNER JOIN
    employee emp ON cte.sub_perno = emp.perno
  INNER JOIN
    employee emp2 ON emp.uniqueKey = emp2.uniqueKey
  INNER JOIN
    employee_manager man ON man.manager_perno = emp2.perno
)

SELECT * FROM cte;
```